# tcrosen typeahead plugin is not functioning on dynamically created input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead, jquery-events

I am using [tcrosen typeahead plugin](https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead) and it's working fine when I use it on static input, but when using it on dynamically created input the plugin isn't executed well. I tried to debug my code using firebug and I noticed that the options are not taken !

This is how I use it :

```
    function displayResult(item, val, text) {
       console.log(item);
       $('.alert').show().html('You selected <strong>' + val + '</strong>: <strong>' + text + '</strong>');
    }
    $('.typeahead-input').typeahead({
       ajax: { url: 'carsController.php?method=searchNames', triggerLength: 1 }, 
       itemSelected: displayResult
    });
```

this is the code that get the dynamic input:

```
    $("#add-typeahead").click(function(){
       $.ajax({url:"ajaxController.php?method=typeahead",success:function(data){
        $("body").append(data);
       });
    });
```

HTML :

```
     <button id="add-typeahead">add typeahead</button><br>
```

Result of ajax call triggered by the button:

```
    <input type="text" class="typeahead-input"  data-provide="typeahead" />
```

Notice that inputs having `class=".typeahead-input"` are created by ajax call triggered by the button .
Any help?

Comment: Where is the code that creates `'.typeahead-input'`?

Comment: I updated the answer to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the typeahead init code in the `success` callback of the first ajax, it should be done **after** the input is added, so after `append()`. Since `append()` is sync and it doesn't provide a callback, you can use `each()` to workaround. So it would be something like this:

```
$("#add-typeahead").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"ajaxController.php?method=typeahead",success:function(data){
        $("body").append(data).each(function () {
            function displayResult(item, val, text) {
               console.log(item);
               $('.alert').show().html('You selected <strong>' + val + '</strong>: <strong>' + text + '</strong>');
            }

            $('.typeahead-input').typeahead({
               ajax: { url: 'carsController.php?method=searchNames', triggerLength: 1 }, 
               itemSelected: displayResult
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works excellent for me.  Thank u very much :)